# convert pdf to png with resize and adding black border

Tags: imagemagick

I try to convert the first page of a book to a png, scale the png to a certain size and add a black border. This is what I tried:

```
convert tmp.pdf\[0\] -background white -alpha remove -border 8 -bordercolor black cover.png
```

[This is the document](http://hpsg.fu-berlin.de/~stefan/transfer/tmp.pdf), I want to convert.

For some reason I have to specify `-background white -alpha remove` since otherwise my white border does not appear or is grey. My problem is that the border that is added is grey not black. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: what does `\[0\]` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked for me is moving the `-bordercolor` option before the actual `-border` statement:

```
convert tmp.pdf\[0\] -background white -alpha remove -bordercolor black -border 8 cover.png
```

should do the trick. I can't find anything in the man page that points to why this should be so, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried moving the two related options together, but did not try this one. Thanks!